# What happened in the end when Susan was waiting for Edward in the resturant?

Tags: plot-explanation, nocturnal-animals

*Nocturnal Animals* ends after showing that Susan was waiting for Edward. Then the movie ends and nothing happens.

What does it actually mean? Did Edward come or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What does the ending of Nocturnal Animals mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69615/49)

Answer (score 2):

That's the point, he didn't show up. That was his way of revenge, he has shaken up her emotions about thir past relationship with the novel and then didn't even show up. This is also covered here in [a similar question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/69615/1190).